# Optimize wrt a partial matrix?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a common optimization problem
$$\arg\min_A \text{tr}(  A^TWA),$$
where $W$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, and $A$ is the matrix to be optimized.

If $A$ is completely unknown, with some scaling constraints, one can reduce this problem into an eigenproblem.

What if $A$ is partially given? That is, I know some entries of $A$ and wish to optimize wrt the unknown entries.

Is there a closed-form solution? What method should I use for this optimization? Pointers to relevant papers/books will be very much appreciated.

---

After some research, I think this is a quadratic programming problem? But I've only seen quadratic problem that solves for a vector $x$. What if I want to solve for a matrix $A$? Is this still a quadratic programming problem?

Comment: Yes, it's still a quadratic programming problem. The "vector" has entries the entries of $A$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks a lot Qiaochu! Are you aware of any off-the-shelf solver for this "matrix quadratic programming problem" (please correct me if there is a better name for this question)? If not, could you please kindly point me to a paper/book that I can start learning how to solve this problem myself?

Comment: The problem formulation doesn't make sense as you are minimizing a matrix objective. What does it mean for that matrix to be small? Is two times the identity matrix smaller than a matrix full of ones? Perhaps you mean something like $\text{trace}(A^TWA)$ or largest eigenvalue of the matrix etc.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks!! I was stupid not to include the trace! Thanks a lot again. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any constraint, you can solve it explicitly. Just write it as $d + c^Tx + x^TQx$ and the solution is given by $-\frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}c$ (assuming $Q$ psd, similar otherwise).

To get it in standard form, write $A = A_0  +\sum_{i=1}^n A_i x_i$ and insert into objective $\text{trace} A^TWA = \text{trace} (A_0  +\sum_{i=1}^n A_i x_i)^TW(A_0  +\sum_{i=1}^n A_i x_i)$. From this you can extract the vectorized model, e.g., $Q_{ij} = \text{trace}~A_i^T W A_j$ etc.

For example, if $A = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 4x_1+x_2\\0 & x_2\end{pmatrix}$ then  $A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the notations here a little? Like, does $A_i$ mean the i-th row of matrix $A$? I am having some hard time understanding your answer, and I presume it's the notation that I was interpreting wrongly. Thanks again.

Comment: No, $A_i$ is a matrix of the same dimension as $A$, added example